# change citation style ( [1-4] to [1]-[4], and [5, 8-9] to [5], [8]-[9] ) with natbib?

Tags: citing, natbib

I have spent a whole day trying to solve the following problem. Please help if you know how to do this.

I am using `natbib` (`\usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma]{natbib}`), and my current citation style looks like `[1-4]`, `[5, 8-9]`.

What is the easiest way to change the citation style to `[1]-[4]` and `[5],[8]-[9]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an unusual requirement.

Please download the modified version of `natbib` found in [`pastebin`](http://pastebin.com/aD1hgDki) (It was too long to paste it here directly). Save this file as `modnatbib.sty` somewhere TeX can find it (your current working directory, for example), and use this package in your document instead of `natbib` with the `numbers,sort&compress` options:

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{modnatbib}
```

A complete example follows.

The file `biblio.bib`:

```
@BOOK{Carey,
   AUTHOR="G. V. Carey",
   TITLE="Mind the Stop: A Brief Guide to Punctuation",
   PUBLISHER="Penguin", YEAR="1958"}

@BOOK{Cooper,
   AUTHOR="Bruce M. Cooper",
   TITLE="Writing Technical Reports",
   PUBLISHER="Penguin", YEAR="1964"}

@BOOK{Fowler-ModernEnglish,
   AUTHOR="H. W. Fowler",
   TITLE="[A Dictionary of] Modern {E}nglish Usage",
   PUBLISHER="Oxford University Press",
   EDITION="2", YEAR="1965"}
   (but first published in 1926)

@BOOK{Fowler-KingsEnglish,
   AUTHOR="H. W. Fowler and F. G. Fowler",
   TITLE="The {K}ing's {E}nglish",
   PUBLISHER="Oxford University Press",
   EDITION="3", YEAR="1931"}
   (but first published in 1906)

@BOOK{Gowers,
   AUTHOR="Sir Ernest Gowers",
   TITLE="The Complete Plain Words",
   PUBLISHER="Penguin", YEAR="1954"}
   (but first published by HMSO)

@BOOK{Hart,
   AUTHOR="Horace Hart",
   TITLE="[Hart's] Rules for Compositors and Readers 
          [at the Oxford University Press]",
   PUBLISHER="Oxford University Press",
   EDITION="39", YEAR="1983"}
   (but first published in 1893)

@BOOK{Partridge,
   AUTHOR="Eric Partridge",
   TITLE="Use and Abuse: a Guide to Good {E}nglish",
   PUBLISHER="Hamish Hamilton",
   EDITION="4", YEAR="1970"}
   (but first published in 1947)

@BOOK{Quirk-CompGram,
   AUTHOR="Randolph Quirk and Sydney Greenbaum and Geoffrey Leach and
           Jan Svartnik",
   TITLE="A Comprehensive Grammar of the {E}nglish Language",
   PUBLISHER="Longman", YEAR="1985"}
```

The `.tex` document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{modnatbib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\cite{Carey,Cooper,Fowler-ModernEnglish}

\cite{Carey,Gowers,Hart,Partridge,Quirk-CompGram}

\cite{Carey,Cooper,Fowler-ModernEnglish,Gowers,Hart,Partridge,Quirk-CompGram}

\cite{Carey,Cooper,Fowler-KingsEnglish,Gowers,Partridge,Quirk-CompGram}

\cite{Carey,Cooper,Fowler-ModernEnglish,Fowler-KingsEnglish,Gowers,Hart,Partridge,Quirk-CompGram}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

In a comment below has been mentioned that the bibliographical style is `IEEEtran`; since this is not one of the styles directly compatible with `natbib`, I'd expect some problems to appear, but the following example (using the same `.bib` file as before) produces no errors and the expected result:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{modnatbib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\cite{Carey,Cooper,Fowler-ModernEnglish}

\cite{Carey,Gowers,Hart,Partridge,Quirk-CompGram}

\cite{Carey,Cooper,Fowler-ModernEnglish,Gowers,Hart,Partridge,Quirk-CompGram}

\cite{Carey,Cooper,Fowler-KingsEnglish,Gowers,Partridge,Quirk-CompGram}

\cite{Carey,Cooper,Fowler-ModernEnglish,Fowler-KingsEnglish,Gowers,Hart,Partridge,Quirk-CompGram}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, thank you so much. Your test example works perfectly. But when I try to use it in my document (using a thesis style and the bibliographystyle is IEEEtran), the references title itself is not shown correctly. I don't know how to add a picture here, but it basically shows as the following (\n denotes next line)"Chapter 7 \n * \n Bibliography \n the list of the references". I am not sure whether I explain the problem clearly, but what changes do you make in the modnatbib file? I can try to adapt the changes you made to my natbib file if it is not too hard, and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @user47181 natbib is not compatible with IEEEtran style.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo. I see, but when I use the standard natbib file, I don't have this problem. Is there a easy way to replce "-" with "]-[" in the natbib file?

Comment: @user47181 Please see my updated answer. Using `IEEEtran` as the bibliographical style my modified version of natbib still produces the desired result (at least in my example code). If you are getting some errors, we need a complete and minimal document (like the ones in my answer) illustrating the problem. I'd think that you could open a new question, since the main object of this one has been solved. I suspect the problem might be in the style for your thesis that you mentioned.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina There is a `natbib` version of the IEEE style  (`IEEEtranN`), on CTAN but not available from the IEEE themselves.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I think you are right. The style of the thesis is not good. I talked to the people in the thesis office today, and they said I can use the citation style I currently have if I can't fix it. I don't want to waste your time on this. But if you are interested, you can download the thesis template at [link](http://gradschool.utah.edu/thesis/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Thesis-Office-LaTex-Template.zip). You should be able to reproduce the problem. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.